# Summation of audio tone

Tags: fft, filters, audio, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

Suppose you transmit at a single tone $\omega\textrm{ rad/sec}$ and you have two receiving microphones $i=1,2$ which sample at $r$ samples per second. Assume you have a direct path with coefficients $h_{d,i}$ and a delay of $\tau_{d,i}$ and one reflected component with coefficients $h_{r,i}$ and a delay of $\tau_{r,i}$ at each microphone.

- How does the received signal look in analog and digital time domain and also how does the FFT look like?
- Do we still perceive only one spike in a particular bin in FFT? Or should you sample appropriately to achieve this?
- How does the FFT look if we have two tones?

Comment: This feels like you're asking us about a very basic introduction on what the spectrum of a signal and the spectral properties of a tapped delay line model are. Are you sure reading a good book isn't the preferred path here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is not very explicit in books

Comment: @Turbo: Any chance of marking answers to your questions as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so suppose your transmitted signal is $s(t)$ and the received signal is $r_i(t)$ in continuous (analog) time .

Then the received signal at the $i^\textrm{th}$ microphone is
$$
r_i(t) = h_{d,i} s(t-\tau_{d,i}) + h_{r,i} s(t-\tau_{r,i})
$$

> How does the received signal look in analog and digital time domain and also how does the FFT look like?

Well if $s(t) \stackrel{\textrm{FT}}{\longleftrightarrow} S(\omega)$ then
$$
r(t) \stackrel{\textrm{FT}}{\longleftrightarrow} R(\omega) = \left [ h_{d,i} e^{-j\omega\tau_{d,i}} + h_{r,i} e^{-j\omega\tau_{r,i}} \right ] S(\omega)
$$
which is simple application of [the time shift property](http://ocw.usu.edu/Electrical_and_Computer_Engineering/Signals_and_Systems/5_6node6.html).

> Do we still perceive only one spike in a particular bin in FFT? Or should you sample appropriately to achieve this?

Once you start talking about 'bins' they we move to discrete-time. In general, unless you are **very** careful with sampling, it's almost impossible to sample a single sinusoid and achieve a spike in just two bins (positive and negative frequencies).  Achieving a spike in just one bin requires a complex exponential which is not really possible with real-world sampling unless you use a specific modulation scheme (which you don't mention).

> How does the FFT look if we have two tones?

Again `FFT` implies discrete time. If you send two tones and sample them, then unless you choose your sampling scheme very cleverly, you will end up with energy in many bins. [See this discussion for more details.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32013/intuition-for-sidelobes-in-fft)

> he math of this is what I am seeking. Assume baseband audio such as speech.

@Turbo If the signal is baseband audio, then there will never be just a single tone. Speech is generally modelled as an [autoregressive (LPC) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding) driven by either white noise or a periodic pulse train. [See figure 2.40 of this reference (screenshot included below for clarity).](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ipollak/ee438/FALL04/notes/Section2.2.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great post. "Achieving a spike in just one bin requires a complex exponential which is not really possible with real-world sampling unless you use a specific modulation scheme (which you don't mention)" The math of this is what I am seeking. Assume baseband audio such as speech.

Comment: @Turbo See my updated answer.

Comment: I understand that but assume we have a tone say at $347$ and $401$
Hz.

Comment: @Turbo So you'll get four spread-out peaks: $\pm 347$Hz and $\pm 401$Hz. They'll be spread out depending on how many samples you take and whether your sampling is synchronous with the sinusoids' generation.

Comment: "whether your sampling is synchronous with the sinusoids' generation" this is the math I am looking for (what happens at different sampling rates and when you are off synchronization and correctly synchronized)

Comment: @Turbo https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/FFT_Not_So_Simple_Sinusoid.html